# Implementation of selection sort in Java

Tags: java

I think I have done the selection sort but I am not sure. Is this really an implementation of selection sort?

```
static void selectionSort()
    {
        int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int n = 0;
        for(int I=0; I<arraySize; I++)
        {

            min = dataArray[I];
            for(int j=I; j<n; j++)
            {
                if(dataArray[min]<dataArray[j])
                  {
                        min = j;
                        if(dataArray[min] < dataArray[I])
                        {
                            int temp = dataArray[I];
                            dataArray[I] = dataArray[min];
                            dataArray[min] = temp;
                        }
                  }
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: How could this works if in the inner cycle you have a condition like `j<n` and `n=0` just before the begin of the first cycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand how your algorithm works at all. Specifically, you do

```
min = dataArray[i];
```

and then later

```
dataArray[min]<dataArray[j]
```

i.e. you treat `min` both as a value in the array, and an index.

Selection sort works as follows:

1. Find the minimum value in the list
2. Swap it with the value in the first position
3. Repeat the steps above for the remainder of the list

([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort))

---

The changes required for your code to accurately implement selection sort would be the following:

1. Change the inner loop to *just* find the index of the smallest element. Call it `minIndex` for instance.
2. Do the swapping *after* the inner loop. i.e., swap element at index `I` with `minIndex`.

Oh, and as DonCallisto points out in the comments, you may want to do `n = dataArray.length` instead of `n = 0` :-)

Comment: i assign the same value of i to j

Comment: `for(int j=I; j<n; j++)` is this cycle ever executed?

Comment: Haha, no that seems like a minor problem too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class SelectionSort {

 /**
  * @Author Chandrasekhara Kota
  */

 public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[]={9,1,8,5,7,-1,6,0,2,2718};
        int sortedArr[]=selectionSort(arr);
        for (int i = 0; i <sortedArr.length; i++) 
        { 
           System.out.println(sortedArr[i]);
        }

      }

      private static int[] selectionSort(int[] arr) { 

      int  minIndex, tmp; 
      int n = arr.length; 
      for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
      { 
              minIndex = i; 
              for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
                   if (arr[j] < arr[minIndex]) 
                        minIndex = j; 
              if (minIndex != i) { 
                    tmp = arr[i]; 
                    arr[i] = arr[minIndex]; 
                    arr[minIndex] = tmp; 
              } 
        }
  return arr; 

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a selection sort implementation in java -

```
public class SelectionSort {

static int intArray[] = { 10, 5, 100, 1, 10000 };

public static void doSort() {
    for (int outer = 0; outer < intArray.length; outer++) {
        int minPosition=outer;
        for(int inner=outer;inner<intArray.length;inner++){
            if(intArray[inner]<intArray[minPosition]){
                minPosition=inner;
            }
        }
        int temp=intArray[minPosition];
        intArray[minPosition]=intArray[outer];
        intArray[outer]=temp;
    }
}

public static void printArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("  " + intArray[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.print("Array Before Sorting->");
    printArray();
    doSort();
    System.out.print("\nArray After Sorting ->");
    printArray();
}
```

}

The above code is picked from - http://www.javabrahman.com/algorithms-in-java/selection-sort-in-java/. This link has detailed explanation on the working of the above code just in case you need the same.